# Why is this DOS batch file that installs Cygwin unattended failing?

Tags: windows, batch, cygwin

After assembling information from all over the Internet, I've managed to come up with a DOS batch script that *should* be working AFAICT, but after the Cygwin setup executable finishes (seemingly successfully), **there is no `bin` directory in the Cygwin root folder**.

Why is it failing?  Fixes welcome! :)

*NB:  It attempts to cleanly install in a directory called `cyg64` in the current user's home directory.*

```
setlocal

if exist %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64 rmdir /s /q %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64
mkdir %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64

set CYGSETUP=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64\cygsetup64.exe

for /f "tokens=4-7 delims=[.] " %%i in ('ver') do (if %%i==Version (set v=%%j.%%k) else (set v=%%i.%%j))
if %v%==6.1 (
  bitsadmin /transfer "CygwinDownload" https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe %CYGSETUP%
) else (
  powershell -command "& { iwr https://www.cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe -OutFile $env:CYGSETUP } "
)

%CYGSETUP% -D -q -R %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64 -a x86_64 -l %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64 -s http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -P openssh,autossh,nano,vim,git

endlocal
```

Comment: Check the `setup.log` and `setup.log.full` in your Cygwin download directory for clues.

Comment: Make sure to install the `cygwin` package. See this question [cygwin1.dll not available error when installing Cygwin](http://superuser.com/q/1030809)

Comment: @DavidPostill:  WRT response #1:  Of course I checked the logs.  Nothing unusual, no error messages.

Comment: @DavidPostill:  WRT response #2:  I added cygwin to the list of packages to install.  The command was `%CYGSETUP% -D -q -R %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64 -a x86_64 -l %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\cyg64 -s http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com -P cygwin,openssh,autossh,nano,vim,git` and it resulted in no difference.  Still no `bin` directory.

Comment: Sorry, no more ideas. I always use the interactive setup ...

Comment: remove "-D" as it just download not install. Additional "-l" should specify a cache directory different from installation

Comment: @matzeri Thanks, it was the -D argument!  Removing it worked; I must've misunderstood the docs.  If you answer this question instead of commenting on it, I'll be happy to mark it as the answer.  FYI, I've never had a problem having my cache directory be inside the cygwin installation directory.  It makes for easy uninstallation later, which is especially what I want in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove "-D" as it just download not install